# Interpretation of a PDF squared

Tags: probability, distributions, density-function, moments

I have a problem where the crucial variable is the integral of the squared PDF of a random variable, i.e.

$\int f(x)^2dx$

How should I interpret this property of a distribution?  If $f(x)$ is gaussian, then this is inversely proportional to the variance, $\sigma^2$, but I don't think this is generally true.

(Note that this is also equal to $\int F(x)f'(x)dx$ ).

Comment: $\int f(x)^2 dx$ is also $\mathbb{E}[f(x)]$ where the expectation is with respect to $X \sim f(x)$. Does this help?

Comment: **Related**: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9926

Comment: Tom, Do the comments and the link answer your question or are you looking for something further?

Comment: Yes I think they're good, & enough to answer my question. Thanks cardinal (not sure how to mark this as answered).