# Why is the asymptotic relative efficiency of the Wilcoxon test $3/\pi$ compared to Student's t-test for normally distributed data?

Tags: nonparametric, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, asymptotics, efficiency, wilcoxon-signed-rank

It is well-known that the asymptotic relative efficiency (ARE) of the Wilcoxon signed rank test is $\frac{3}{\pi} \approx 0.955$ compared to Student's *t*-test, if the data are drawn from a normally distributed population. This is true for both the basic one-sample test and the variant for two independent samples (the Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney U). It is also the ARE of a Kruskal-Wallis test compared to an ANOVA *F*-test, for normal data.

Does this remarkable (for me, one of the "[most unexpected appearances of $\pi$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/689315/what-are-some-interesting-cases-of-pi-appearing-in-situations-that-are-not)") and remarkably simple result have have an insightful, remarkable or simple proof?

Comment: Given the appearance of $\pi$ in the normal cdf, the appearance of $\pi$ in the ARE shouldn't really be *all* that surprising. I'll hazard an answer but it will take a while to make a good one.

Comment: https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=UEuQEM5RjWgC&pg=PA198&dq=van+der+vaart+mann+whitney&hl=ja&sa=X&ei=6ZegVKO2Io3j8AXrhICYBg&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=van%20der%20vaart%20mann%20whitney&f=false

Comment: @Glen_b Indeed - I've seen a "why does $\pi$ appear so much in statistics" discussion before (though can't remember if it was on CV or not) and "because of the normal distribution" I know crops up a lot, but $3/\pi$ is still pleasantly surprising the first time you see it. [For comparison](http://web.as.uky.edu/statistics/users/pbreheny/621/F10/notes/10-19.pdf) the ARE of Mann-Whitney vs two-sample t-test is 3 on exponential data, 1.5 on double exponential and 1 on uniform - much rounder!

Comment: +1 I have been wondering about that myself every time I saw it mentioned here on CV. Why don't you post this example in the linked discussion on  maths.SE?

Comment: @Silverfish I've linked the page 197 of van der Vaart "Asymptotic Statistics". For one-sample, sign-tests have ARE $2/\pi$ relative to t-test.

Comment: @amoeba Good idea, http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1084050/72968

Comment: @Silverfish ... and at the logistic it's $(\pi/3)^2$. There are quite a few of the well-known AREs (in either one or two sample cases) involving $\pi$ and quite a few that are simple ratios of integers.

Comment: AREs come down to ratios of slope (for one-tailed) or second derivatives (for two-tailed) of power curves at the null.

Comment: @Glen_b Can you elaborate on how slope of the power curves calculated?

Comment: @Khashaa If I give an answer, some discussion of that should be in there.

Comment: For one-sample signed rank test, it seems to be $3/\pi$. For one-sample sign test, it is $2/\pi$. So, we clarified our position. I think it is a good sign.

Comment: @Glen_b You're quite right, I completely misread what Khashaa said. I have rolled back my question to its original - it seems I got it right first time round! I'd be perfectly satisfied with an explanation of the $3/\pi$ for either rank sum or signed rank variant of Wilcoxon; it makes perfect sense for the plain sign test to have a lower ARE.

Comment: I ended up discussing both (though very briefly) since they both involve the same integral.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Brief sketch of ARE for one-sample $t$-test, signed test and the signed-rank test**

I expect the long version of @Glen_b's answer includes detailed analysis for two-sample signed rank test along with the intuitive explanation of the ARE. So I'll skip most of the derivation. (one-sample case, you can find the missing details in Lehmann TSH).

**Testing Problem**: Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be a random sample from location model $f(x-\theta)$, symmetric about zero. We are to compute ARE of signed test, signed rank test for the hypothesis $H_0: \theta=0$ relative to t-test.

To assess the relative efficiency of tests, only local alternatives are considered because consistent tests have power tending to 1 against fixed alternative. 
Local alternatives that give rise to nontrivial asymptotic power is often of the form $\theta_n=h/\sqrt{n}$ for fixed $h$, which is called *Pitman drift* in some literature.

Our task ahead is

- find the limit distribution of each test statistic under the null
- find the limit distribution of each test statistic under the alternative
- compute the local asymptotic power of each test

**Test statisics and asymptotics**

1. t-test (given the existence of $\sigma$)  $$t_n=\sqrt{n}\frac{\bar{X}}{\hat{\sigma}}\to_dN(0,1)\quad \text{under the null}$$ 
   $$t_n=\sqrt{n}\frac{\bar{X}}{\hat{\sigma}}\to_dN(h/\sigma,1)\quad \text{under the alternative }\theta=h/\sqrt{n}$$

   - so the test that rejects if $t_n>z_\alpha$ has asymptotic power function
     $$1-\Phi\left(z_\alpha-h\frac{1}{\sigma}\right)$$
2. signed test $S_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}1\{X_i>0\}$
   $$\sqrt{n}\left(S_n-\frac{1}{2}\right)\to_dN\left(0,\frac{1}{4}\right)\quad \text{under the null }$$
   $$\sqrt{n}\left(S_n-\frac{1}{2}\right)\to_dN\left(hf(0),\frac{1}{4}\right)\quad \text{under the alternative }$$ and has local asymptotic power
   $$1-\Phi\left(z_\alpha-2hf(0)\right)$$
3. signed-rank test $$W_n=n^{-2/3}\sum_{i=1}^{n}R_i1\{X_i>0\}\to_dN\left(0,\frac{1}{3}\right)\quad \text{under the null }$$
   $$W_n\to_dN\left(2h\int f^2,\frac{1}{3}\right)\quad \text{under the alternative }$$
   and has local asymptotic power
   $$1-\Phi\left(z_\alpha-\sqrt{12}h\int f^2\right)$$

Therefore, $$ARE(S_n)=(2f(0)\sigma)^2$$
$$ARE(W_n)=(\sqrt{12}\int f^2\sigma)^2$$
If $f$ is standard normal density, $ARE(S_n)=2/\pi$, $ARE(W_n)=3/\pi$

If $f$ is uniform on [-1,1], $ARE(S_n)=1/3$, $ARE(W_n)=1/3$

**Remark on the derivation of distribution under the alternative**

There are of course many ways to derive the limiting distribution under the alternative. One general approach is to use Le Cam's third lemma. Simplified version of it states

> Let $\Delta_n$ be the log of the likelihood ratio. For some statistic
>   $W_n$, if 
>   $$ (W_n,\Delta_n)\to_d N\left[\left(\begin{array}{c}
> \mu\\
> -\sigma^2/2
> \end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{cc}
> \sigma^2_W & \tau \\
> \tau & \sigma^2/2 
> \end{array}\right)\right]\\
> $$
>   under the null, then $$W_n\to_d N\left(\mu+\tau,\sigma^2_W\right)\quad\text{under the alternative}$$

For quadratic mean differentiable densities, local asymptotic normality and contiguity are automatically satisfied, which in turn implies Le Cam lemma. 
Using this lemma, we only need to compute $\mathrm{cov}(W_n,\Delta_n)$ under the null. $\Delta_n$ obeys LAN $$\Delta_n\approx \frac{h}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{i=1}^{n}l(X_i)-\frac{1}{2}h^2I_0$$ where $l$ is score function, $I_0$ is information matrix.
Then, for instance, for signed test $S_n$
$$\mathrm{cov}(\sqrt{n}(S_n-1/2),\Delta_n)=-h\mathrm{cov}\left(1\{X_i>0\},\frac{f'}{f}(X_i)\right)=h\int_0^\infty f'=hf(0)$$

Comment: +1 I wasn't going to go into quite this much detail (indeed, with your answer covering things quite nicely already, I probably won't add anything to what I have now) so if you want to put more detail, don't hold back on my account. I would have been several days yet (and still for less than you have already), so it's a good thing you came in.

Comment: This is a nice answer particularly for adding in Le Cam's lemma (+1). It seems to me there is quite a big jump between establishing the asymptotics in 1, 2, and 3, and the "therefore" bit where you write the AREs. I think if I were writing this up, I'd define asymptotic efficiency at this point (or maybe earlier, so the upshot of points 1, 2 and 3 would be the AEs not just local asymptotic powers in each case) and then the step to the AREs would be much easier for future readers to follow.

Comment: Perhaps it is worth specifying your $H_1$? One-sided and two-sided cases have different-looking asymptotic powers (though they lead to the same AREs).

Comment: Feel free to edit my answer or append it to the OP.

Comment: @Khashaa Thanks. I shall edit your post when I have the right stuff in front of me. Would you mind clarifying the meaning of the $*$ in the final equation?

Comment: @Silverfish That should be the multiplication.

Answer (score 7):

This has nothing to do with explaining why $\pi$ appears (which was explained nicely by others) but may help intuitively.  The Wilcoxon test is a $t$-test on the ranks of $Y$ whereas the parametric test is computed on the raw data.  The efficiency of the Wilcoxon test with respect to the $t$-test is the square of the correlation between the scores used for the two tests.  As $n\rightarrow \infty$ the squared correlation converges to $\frac{\pi}{3}$.  You can easily see this empirically using R:

```
n <- 1000000; x <- qnorm((1:n)/(n+1)); cor(1:n, x)^2; 3/pi
[1] 0.9549402
[1] 0.9549297
n <- 100000000; x <- qnorm((1:n)/(n+1)); cor(1:n, x)^2; 3/pi
[1] 0.9549298
[1] 0.9549297
```

Comment: This is indeed a very helpful comment. Is it slightly conceptually closer to do `n <- 1e6; x <- rnorm(n); cor(x, rank(x))^2` (which obviously produces the same result)?

Comment: (People intrigued by Frank's comment may want to look at [this question about the equivalence of Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney U and a *t*-test on the ranks](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/55285/equivalence-of-mann-whitney-u-test-and-t-test-on-ranks).)

Comment: something I don't understand about this answer is that the correlation is *higher* for lower values of $n$ (I think the proximal reason is that we don't see the tails very well for smaller $n$). Naively that implies that the relative efficiency of the Wilcoxon is *higher* for small $n$, which surprises me ... ?? (I might do some simulations, but (a) if there's an easy answer ... and (b) am I missing a conceptual point somewhere?)

Comment: To my recollection the small sample efficiency of both the Wilcoxon signed rank test and the W-M-W are a bit lower than the asymptotic value on shift alternatives at the normal distribution.

Answer (score 5):

Short version: The basic reason with the Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney under a shift alternative is that finding the asymptotic relative efficiency (WMW/t) corresponds to evaluating $12\sigma^2[\int f^2(x) dx]^2$ where $f$ is the common density at the null and $\sigma$ is the common variance.

So at the normal, $f^2$ is effectively a scaled version of $f$; its integral will have a $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}$ term; when squared, that's the source of the $\frac{ \;}{\pi}$.

The same term - with the same integral - is involved in the ARE for the signed rank test, so it takes the same value.

For the sign test relative to t, the ARE is $4\sigma^2f(0)^2$... and $f(0)^2$ again has a $\frac{ \;}{\pi}$ in it.

So essentially it's as I said in comments; $\pi$ is in the ARE for the Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney vs the two-sample t test, for the Wilcoxon signed rank test vs the one-sample t and the sign test vs the one-sample t test (in each case at the normal) quite literally because it appears in the normal density.

Reference:

J. L. Hodges and E. L. Lehmann (1956),
"The Efficiency of Some Nonparametric Competitors of the t-Test",
*Ann. Math. Statist.*, **27**:2, 324-335.

Comment: I like the explanation for the intuition for the appearance of $\pi$ in the denominator; is it essentially coincidence that the [Renyi entropy](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9926/is-there-any-use-for-the-quantity-int-fx2-dx-in-statistics-or-information) turns up in the WMW/Wilcoxon integrals?

Comment: @Silverfish That $\int f^2 dx$ turns up is certainly not coincidence. However, that's not because that's connected to Rényi entropy, or at least I don't see any direct connection. We're getting into stuff I don't really know about now, though.

Comment: @Silverfish It's only a Renyi entropy for $\alpha=2$. Otherwise, it is just a plain old square that can come up in a million different ways.

Comment: I should perhaps add to my answer that once you attribute it to a normal distribution,  from there it's not hard to find a connection to a circle. Often when you find a $\pi$ you can find a circle hidden in there somewhere.